# intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); not launching Activity in new Task

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to launch a new task on Click of a button. but not working as per flag given. it working like standard launch mode.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

What are flag for launch mode `SingleTask` and `SingleInstance`?

Answer (score 2):

try and use these code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can set a flag on the intent launching the activity:  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i set android:launchMode="singleInstance" in manifest in java as well. but when i activity is launched. it is launched as in             android:launchMode="standard"